# Change edit form page behind Edit Item in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, edit-form

I have three view pages for a list. I want different edit forms for each view page.

How can I link 3 edit forms to respective view and they should open through "edit Item" link in the top ribbon.

[image]

I am using SharePoint designer 2010.